# How to extract value from one S4 class

Tags: r, r-s4

Probably a naive question:

```
>library("coin")
> b <-independence_test(c(23,56,18) ~ c(1,3,2),teststat = "quad")
> b

    Asymptotic General Independence Test

data:  c(23, 56, 18) by c(1, 3, 2)
chi-squared = 1.2772, df = 1, p-value = 0.2584
```

I tried to find a place to extract this pValue (0.2584) but failed. Please help.  Thanks in advance.

Comment: have your tried `pvalue(b)`?

Comment: Great, thank you very much!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It was hard to guess but I always look on the S4 class structure with `str` function and then I wound out that there is test statictic and `pvalue` function available in the object. I was looking for `print` function for this object as
calling `b` is equivalent to call `print(b)` but I couldn't find

```
class(b)
coin:::print.QuadTypeIndependenceTest
```

By the way the final answer is

```
b <-independence_test(c(23,56,18) ~ c(1,3,2),teststat = "quad")
b
str(b)
b@distribution@pvalue(b@statistic@teststatistic)
```

Also it might help to read the vignette first https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/coin/vignettes/coin_implementation.pdf