# Extract Information from R's Johansen Procedure (ca.jo) summary

Tags: r, time-series

I would like to extract the critical value of test (and only this) information after running the `ca.jo()` function from the model summary in R.

```
library(urca)
data(finland)
sjf <- finland
sjf.vecm <- ca.jo(sjf, ecdet = "none", type="eigen", K=2,
spec="longrun", season=4)
summary(sjf.vecm)
```

As shown, while `summary()` returns a long list of results, it does not provide the functionality of getting more specified information through the use of `summary(sjf.vecm)$[target info]`.

```
###################### 
# Johansen-Procedure # 
###################### 

Test type: maximal eigenvalue statistic (lambda max) , with linear trend 

Eigenvalues (lambda):
[1] 0.30932660 0.22599561 0.07308056 0.02946699

Values of teststatistic and critical values of test:

          test 10pct  5pct  1pct
r <= 3 |  3.11  6.50  8.18 11.65
r <= 2 |  7.89 12.91 14.90 19.19
r <= 1 | 26.64 18.90 21.07 25.75
r = 0  | 38.49 24.78 27.14 32.14

Eigenvectors, normalised to first column:
(These are the cointegration relations)

           lrm1.l2    lny.l2    lnmr.l2    difp.l2
lrm1.l2  1.0000000  1.000000  1.0000000   1.000000
lny.l2  -0.9763252 -1.323191 -0.9199865   1.608739
lnmr.l2 -7.0910749 -2.016033  0.2691516  -1.375342
difp.l2 -7.0191097 22.740851 -1.8223931 -15.686927

Weights W:
(This is the loading matrix)

           lrm1.l2       lny.l2      lnmr.l2      difp.l2
lrm1.d 0.033342108 -0.020280528 -0.129947614 -0.002561906
lny.d  0.022544782 -0.005717446  0.012949130 -0.006265406
lnmr.d 0.053505000  0.046876449 -0.007367715  0.002173242
difp.d 0.005554849 -0.017353903  0.014561151  0.001531004
```

How can I get the results only from the critical value table, reformat it in some way and produce a table that looks like:

```
Test   |  test |  10pct | 5pct  | 1pct
----------------------------------------
r <= 3 |  3.11 |  6.50  | 8.18  | 11.65
r <= 2 |  7.89 | 12.91  | 14.90 | 19.19
r <= 1 | 26.64 | 18.90  | 21.07 | 25.75
r = 0  | 38.49 | 24.78  | 27.14 | 32.14
```

Comment: I actually found the solution from the hint provided by another thread (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32639460/how-to-extract-value-from-one-s4-class). In this case, `summary(sjf.vecm)@cval` works!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can save the results of the `summary` and then explore its contents with

```
S = summary(sjf.vecm)
str(S)
```

Looking at that, you can see how to get the result that you want.

```
cbind(S@teststat, S@cval)
                   10pct  5pct  1pct
r <= 3 |  3.110626  6.50  8.18 11.65
r <= 2 |  7.892417 12.91 14.90 19.19
r <= 1 | 26.642484 18.90 21.07 25.75
r = 0  | 38.489175 24.78 27.14 32.14
```